# GoDaddy Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: .net, api, post, nuget, onesignal

i am trying to send push notifications via One Signal from GoDaddy using below code:

[code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLgho.png)

and i get response of "Unable to connect to the remote server" after waiting for a few seconds. my first thought was that GoDaddy are blocking traffic to this endpoint but I have contacted them and they said they are not blocking any outgoing traffic.

This code works absolutely fine on localhost and on other servers that this application was hosted on previously.

I have also tried to implement this using OneSignal.RestAPIv3.Client nuget package but get the same issue.

Any help with regards to code or GoDaddy settings will be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to consult this matter to Godaddy team.